# Bad network when openvpn is enabled

Tags: networking, 16.04, vpn, openvpn

I use openvpn on my Ubuntu 16.04 before it was 14.10 and the problem is also attended. 
When vpn is enabled network works unstable. A few minutes it works fine but then breaking - long hanging *resolving host* and next shows an error:

> There is no Internet connection DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET.

A few minutes later the network starts to work again.
 

 Disconnecting from  vpn  solves issue

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/openvpn stop
```

But what's wrong with network when vpn is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to connect to the internet through VPN and you also have access OpenVPN server side then you might want to check the OpenVPN server conf file. There should be options starting with *push "dhcp-option DNS*, try changing DNS servers to something else, example OpenDNS, whis are 208.67.222.220 and 208.67.222.222.
Also after making changes in server conf you have to reload the service

```
    sudo service openvpn reload
```